# Как реализовать вызов циклов for внутри самих себя необходимое количество раз через рекурсию

Tags: java, алгоритм, рекурсия

Друзья, написал такую функцию перебора натуральных чисел, на вход которой подается число, определяющее до какого разряда будет перебор, то есть если на вход 3, то перебор будет от 1 до 999.

```
public class Solution3 {
public static void doAlgorithm(int howManyDigitInLine) {

    for (int c = 1; c <= 9; c++) {
        System.out.println(c + " ");
        for (int k = c; k <= 9; k++) {
            System.out.println(c + " " + k);
            for (int v = k; v <= 9; v++) {
                System.out.println(c + " " + k + " " + v);

            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    doAlgorithm(3);
}}
```

суть алгоритма в том что он исключает из перебора повторы комбинаций - если было число 123, то в перебор уже не попадают числа 321 213 231
вывод будет такой:
1    11   111   112   113   114   115   116   117   118   119   12   122   123   124   125   126   127   128   129   13   133 и так до 999

но сейчас тут параметр который подается в эту функцию никак не работает, потому что я написал 3 вложенных цикла вручную, то есть если дописать еще один вложенный цикл for вручную, то получится перебор до 9999, но мне нужно, чтобы естественно работало в зависимости от параметра на входе, я пытался сделать рекурсией и пробовал примерно такое:

```
public class Solution2 {
static String result1 = "";

public static void recursionEnumeration(int xx, int counter) {
    if (counter == 0) {
    result1 = "";
    }
    for (int xx1 = xx; xx1 <= 9; xx1++) {
        result1 += "" + xx1;
        String result2 = result1;
        //System.out.println(xx + " " + xx1);
        if (counter != 0) {
            recursionEnumeration(xx1, counter - 1);
        }
        System.out.println(result1);
        result1 = result2;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    recursionEnumeration(1, 2);

}}
```

но на выходе как не пытался - получаю совсем не то.
Если кто-то может, подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли это сделать рекурсией и каким образом, или может есть другой способ.. хотя бы направьте в нужное русло..

Comment: если подается 3 , то надо пройти от 1 до 999?

Comment: вам здесь не нужна рекурсия, это довольно просто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекурсией сделать можно.

int stopRecurtion = 9999;

Давайте определим функцию.

public void recurtionEnumeration(int prefix, startIndex){

for(index = startIndex; index<=9; index++) {
    If ((prefix*10 + index) > stopRecurtion) return;
    System.out.println(prefix * 10 + index);
    recurtionEnumeration (prefix*10 + index, index);
  }
}

Извиняюсь за оформление набираю с телефона

Comment: Пометить не забудьте

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void doAlgorithm(int howManyDigitInLine) {
    int limit =(int) Math.pow(10,howManyDigitInLine);
    for (int i = 1; i < limit; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }    
}
```

Comment: да, точно, если 2, то иду до 99 , если 1, то иду до 9, если 4, то до 9999  - вы получаете ответ в соответствии с описанием задачи. если вам надо исключить из повтора какие-либо цифры, то можно завести коллекцию типа сет и добавлять туда в ходе перебора цифры, которые необходимо в дальнейшем исключить. в принципе, это тоже несложно, я просто пока не совсем поннял алгоритма. нам надо вычислить в числе все возможнве комбинации цифр и исключить их из дальнейшего вывода?